# Android Notification when web service data change

Tags: android, notifications

I'm  trying to send notifications when data of database changes.

The structure:

```
        DATABASE
       /        \\
     APP         WEB
```

APP: Only reads the data.

WEB: Reads and edits data.

I have an app and it takes data from a database (names, surnames, phone numbers..). In the web's backend I can change this data, add new names, edit, delete.  When I change this data in the database I want to show a notification in my app like. "New name was added". How can I get these notifications to display?

Answer (score 1):

use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) for sending notifications to the device from the server. Server changes the data and will also tell the device that data is changed by sending the notification.